# Accessing Two containers on from browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, containers

I have launch EC2 ubuntu instance and security group for this is instance allows 22,80,443 ports from 0.0.0.0/0.
Now i have installed docker on this EC2 instance.Then i have created an apache2 container and also mapped the port to access from browser using below command

```
      sudo docker run -p 80:80 -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Then i create an lampstack conatiner and tried to map port using below command

```
      sudo docker run -p 443:443 -t -i linode/lamp /bin/bash
```

Now docker ps gives me below

```
 CONTAINER ID  IMAGE       COMMAND      CREATED STATUS   PORTS   Name      
 d0751e67fd69  linode/lamp "/bin/bash"  4 min   Up 4   0.0.0.0:443>443/tcp   
                                                    affectionate_hamilton
 0fb4e13a272a  ubuntu       "/bin/bash"  11 minutes     0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp     
                                                      vigorous_robinson
```

When i take the public ip of my EC2 machine and put in browser i can see the apache page but how can i assess my Lampstack page ?

Please correct me if i have done port mapping incorrectly

Comment: I think you should write @IP:443 to access it or, https://@IP

Comment: @MehdiBenmesssaoud i tried but no luck

Comment: @AWS_Beginner what's the o/p?

Comment: @AWS_Beginner Try to change the exposed port 443 to 8080 for example

Comment: Port 443 is by default used for HTTPS traffic. What is the type of traffic set for port 443 in your security group?

Answer (score 0):

You only need the LAMP container and in that one you should map the port 80:

```
sudo docker run -d --name lamp -t -p 80:80 linode/lamp top
```

Check that the container is up and running:

```
sudo docker ps --filter name=lamp
```

Now start the services:

```
sudo docker exec -ti lamp service apache2 start
sudo docker exec -ti lamp service mysql start
```

Test your setup from host:

```
curl http://localhost
```

If you want to test a connection from a different container you can start a separate ubuntu container that links to your original container "lamp":

```
docker run -ti --rm --link lamp --name ubuntu-box ubuntu bash
```

Inside the container install curl and test your connection:

```
apt update && apt-get install curl -y
curl http://lamp
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.First container is ubuntu in which i install apache. And this is not any task as i want to learn docker so i was trying to access two different containers which are present in same host,so here i need both the containers.

Comment: Your post never mentioned that. I added the response to implement this scenario. I hope now you can test connection between 2 containers.